# Can replace record, but cannot insert record in php / mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, replace, insert

I am having a really odd problem here, in that I can replace a record but cant create new ones for some reason. If I create an album with id = 2hdfhh4 and then submit an album with the same id the details get updated. If I try posting a new album nothing happens, I don't even get any errors either ?.

```
    include("connect.php");
    $photostring = implode(',',$photos);
    $albumname = htmlspecialchars($albumname);

        $sqlA = <<<SQL
        SELECT *
        FROM `albumorders`
        WHERE albumid = '$albumid' 
        LIMIT 1
    SQL;

    if(!$resultA = $db->query($sqlA)){
        die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
    }
    while($rowA = $resultA->fetch_assoc()){
        if ($albumid = $rowA['albumid']){
            mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE albumorders SET `albumid`='$albumid',`albumname`='$albumname',`imagesordered`='$photostring' WHERE `albumid`='$albumid'");
            }
            else {
                mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO albumorders (`albumid`,`albumname`,`imagesordered`) VALUES ('$albumid','$albumname','$photostring')");
            }
        }
```

My table looks like this :

[image]

Comment: It wasnt giving any error

Comment: Why did you use while if you give limit 1 to your sql?

Answer (score 4):

```
if ($albumid = $rowA['albumid']){
```

is an assignment, so it always evaluates to `true` and you won't get to the `else` part.

It should be:

```
if ($albumid == $rowA['albumid']) {
```

Comment: Whats even more odd is if I take the insert out of the if / while loop it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are double checking the value.

The SQL Query will check whether the row with $albumid is available or not.

So, what you can do is you can directly check the sql result. If sql result is avaiable you update the row else you insert into data into the table...

Comment: How do I check the result is available ?